# Combine sklearn FeatureUnion and StackingClassifier in Pipeline for text data

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to combine Sklearn FeatureUnion and StackingClassifier in Pipeline in order to make predictions based on a DataFrame containing both numeric and text data. I am able to use FeatureUnion in the Pipeline and input them into a gridSearch but once I add the StackingClassifier, the fit goes well but the predict step return me an error saying : `'nonetype' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Here's what my data looks like:

| x1 | x2 | text_data | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 3 | stack over flow question | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | stack over flow is good | 1 |

Here's what I tried:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['x1','x2','text_data']], df["label"])

get_text_data = FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x["text_data"], validate = False)
get_numeric_data = FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x[['x1','x2']], validate = False)

numeric_pipeline = Pipeline([('selector', get_numeric_data)])
text_pipeline = Pipeline([('selector', get_text_data), ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(tokenizer = custom_vect))])

featureunionvect = FeatureUnion([('numeric_pipe', numeric_pipeline), 
                                 ('text_pipe', text_pipeline)])

clf1 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
clf2 = GaussianNB()
lr = LogisticRegression()

pipe = Pipeline([('vect', featureunionvect),
                 ('classifier', PipelineHelper([
                     ('sclf', StackingClassifier(classifiers = [clf1, clf2], meta_classifier = lr))
                 ]))])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.predict(X_test)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-86330f7f8ed9> in <module>
     21 
     22 pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
---> 23 pipe.predict(X_test)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    118 
    119         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 120         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    121         # update the docstring of the returned function
    122         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    417         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
    418             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
--> 419         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    420 
    421     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='_final_estimator')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipelinehelper\__init__.py in predict(self, x)
    170         if self.optional:
    171             raise ValueError('a classifier can not be optional')
--> 172         return self.selected_model.predict(x)
    173 
    174     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='selected_model')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Here's the code result if I run it without the predict step:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('vect',
                 FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[('numeric',
                                                 Pipeline(steps=[('selector',
                                                                  FunctionTransformer(func=<function <lambda> at 0x0000015D2D308CA0>))])),
                                                ('text',
                                                 Pipeline(steps=[('selector',
                                                                  FunctionTransformer(func=<function <lambda> at 0x0000015D0CE9E430>)),
                                                                 ('vectorizer',
                                                                  CountVectorizer(tokenizer=<function tokenizer at 0x0000015D27824E50>))]))])),
                ('classifier',
                 PipelineHelper(available_models={'sclf': StackingClassifier(classifiers=[RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1),
                                                                                          GaussianNB()],
                                                                             meta_classifier=LogisticRegression())}))])
```

Comment: You sure get this error after a successful `pipe.fit()`?

Comment: Yes, I just added the result of the fit to my question